# Setting up Gatsby on GitHub Pages

Tags: javascript, github, github-pages, gatsby

I've been having a nightmare setting up a reactjs web app/webpack etc myself. So now I'm using Gatsby, which has been a life saver!!!!

I've installed Gatsby locally using NPM.  And I want to deploy it to my Github page...  It's kinda worked...

Here are the instructions I've followed:
https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/deploy-gatsby/#github-pages

And here is what I'm seeing on my GitHub.io page:
https://reenaverma.github.io/

Its not the default starter pack index page/content, I'm seeing on my localhost 8000.

I can see on my Github repo the correct content has deployed to Github:
https://github.com/ReenaVerma/reenaverma.github.io

But I'm not actually seeing it on my URL.  It looks like it's surfacing my readme first... How can I fix this?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see that your gatsby project is your **main gh-pages**. Therefore, you need to put your build in the **master branch** not in the **gh-pages branch**.

So you need to put your src code in a branch of your choice & in the **master branch** you put your generated build.

Change your script to the following

```
"scripts": {
    "deploy": "gatsby build && gh-pages -b master -d public",
}
```

Comment: ok thank you!... how do I do this?  I just followed the gatsby instructions.....  I'm not sure how this setup happened...

Comment: @ReenaVerma change your script for deploy to   "deploy": "gatsby build --prefix-paths && gh-pages -b master -d public",

Comment: Hi @Melchia, Hoping you could help out!  I've had to recreate my app again and I've used a slightly different gatsby starter pack, but run into the same deployment issue as above....  I've used your recommendation, but it's not working this time....  Was wondering if youcould help out?

Here's the specific issue here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50610679/gatsby-deployment-to-github-failing

Comment: got it working!  I didnt install this:
npm install gh-pages --save-dev

Comment: Sorry for the late answer but I saw that you got it working!

Comment: just make sure if you're using custom domain name that you keep your CNAME file in the static folder of gatsby, so that it won'be rewritten after build/deploy https://konstantin.io/gatsby-github/#custom-domain-name